# Entity Framework adding same entity twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm facing a strange situation in Entity Framework. In a project I work on, we have a method with a nasty code with more than 1.5K lines. This method adds an order and a customer. That customer entity has a primary key which is an int identity. Sometimes, which I couldn't identify yet, that customer is added twice.

A few SaveChanges are called throughout the method and I think that's the problem, since I made a test creating a customer adding to the context and then calling SaveChanges twice.

Like this:

```
_context.Customers.Add(customer);
_context.SaveChanges();
_context.SaveChanges();
```

We know that's duplicate because we control Customers by Email field. Should be the primary key or at least unique index. Now it's too late to make these changes.

I create another simple project and tried to reproduce but didn't happen.
I've little experience with EF, tried to Google, little or no luck and I really hate EF.

It's a Asp.net MVC app, dotnet 4.5.2 with EF 6.3.1.

Comment: Create a method that uses a separate context to check if there's duplicate. Place that regularly throughout your code so you can track down the point where the duplicate is created.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I tried that, same behaviour.

Comment: Are you manipulating the entity state anywhere like `context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Added`?

Comment: *"with more than 1.5K lines [...] create another simple project and tried to reproduce but didn't happen"* - Based on the latter statement it doesn't really sound like *EF* is creating duplicate entries, it sounds like *somewhere in that code* the logic being expressed is creating duplicate entries.  Not sure what other "answers" we could provide other than "try debugging".

Comment: @PaulAbbott No. We've "_context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;" But somewhere else in the code...

Comment: @David I agree with you. I'm debugging but it's a nightmare. I thought there is something I could missed...

Comment: @ramires.cabral: At the very least you should be able to narrow the specific area of code by placing breakpoints and examining the state of the DB while paused.  A binary search approach should zero in within a few attempts.  Assuming the behavior is reliably reproducible.  (Determinism is pretty key when debugging.)

Comment: @David "Assuming the behavior is reliably reproducible". Well it's not... Anyway, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am little late but. You can Use

```
_context.Customers.Add(customer);
_context.SaveChanges();
_context.Customers.Add(customer);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This will add two customers with diffrent IDs.